# How to swap the value of column in a single query in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I have a table  that looks like this:

```
 id name  date
 1   prabhat  22-12-1989
 2   Ashok  20-12-1978
 3   prabhat  22-12-1986
 4   Ashok  20-12-1974
 5   prabhat  22-12-1889
 6   Ashok  20-12-1900
```

And I want to change  the name from prabhat --> Ashok and Ashok--> prabhat in a single query

Thanks.

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: i was  doing  it with three update command using temp string.

Answer (score 5):

One clever trick here would be to self-join your table on the `name` columns matching the names `prabhat` on one table and `Ashok` on the other (or vice-versa).  Then you can simply do a single `SET` to update the value.

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON (t1.name = 'prabhat' AND t2.name = 'Ashok') OR
       (t1.name = 'Ashok'   AND t2.name = 'prabhat')
SET t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to handle this would be to use a `CASE` statement to conditionally update the `name` column:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET t.name = CASE WHEN t.name = 'ashok'   THEN 'prabhat'
                  WHEN t.name = 'prabhat' THEN  'ashok'
             END
```

Comment: You do not really need the replace() calls, just have 'prabhat' or 'ashok' inthe then clauses. You may also want to use a where clause to speed the update up. Plus it would not hurt to provide some explanation as to how the suggested query works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do select, it is easy:

```
SELECT id, `date`,
  if (name = 'prabhat', 'Ashok', if (name = 'Ashok', 'prabhat', name)) AS name
FROM tab
```

If you update, you need to use a temp-value (which does not exist in the tab.name)

```
-- check if temp name exists
SELECT count(*) FROM tab WHERE name = 'NON-EXIST-temp-name';

UPDATE tab SET name = 'NON-EXIST-temp-name' 
WHERE name = 'prabhat';

UPDATE tab SET name = 'prabhat' 
WHERE name = 'Ashok';

UPDATE tab SET name = 'Ashok' 
WHERE name = 'NON-EXIST-temp-name';
```

After I answered, I found Tim also comes up with a clever answer, if you are not logically strong, probably try this straight forward method